# How does copy_reg save the reduce/rebuild functions

Tags: python, pickle

Suppose I use `copy_reg.pickle` to register a reduce function, like the following.

```
import copy_reg, copy, pickle

some_global_variable = 10

class C(object):
  def __init__(self, a):
    self.a = a
    self.b = some_global_variable

def unpickle_c(a):
  c = C(a)
  c.b = some_global_variable

def pickle_c(c):
  return unpickle_c, (c.a,)

copy_reg.pickle(C, pickle_c)
```

I have a few questions:

1. Is the function `unpickle_c` saved as a serialized object and called upon unpickling? If this is true, does it mean I cannot access to states outside of the function, such as `some_global_variable` in the `unpickle_c` function? Or will the global variable be saved as part of the serialized function object as well?
2. If the above is not true, is `unpickle_c` saved as some identifier and the function is simply located and called upon unpickling? If this is true, does it mean, if the module containing `unpickle_c` has not been imported yet upon unpickling, it will be imported?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just got the answer from experimenting the pickle module myself. Basically the bullet 2 is true. From inspecting the pickled string, the module name and the name of the rebuild function is saved. The module is to be imported upon unpickling and then the function from that module is to be called.